# How to construct an empty Iterable subclass, generically, and in Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala.js

Normally `breakout` would aid in conversion from one collection to another, but it doesn't seem to be able to infer the necessary colleciton constuctor for C:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

object Utils {

  implicit class IterableExtra[T, C[X] <: Iterable[X]](val list: C[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def empty: C[T] = Iterable.empty[T].map(x => x)(breakOut)

  }
}
```

Ideally this would work with minimal reflection, so that it might work in scala.js

**Update** I was also trying to use this in a different way, and I forgot to have the implicit at the outermost level:

```
  def testIterableEmpty[B, I[X] <: Iterable[X]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[I[B], B, I[B]]): I[B] = {
    def emptyIter: I[B] = cbf().result()
    emptyIter
  }


scala> val x: List[Int] = testIterableEmpty[Int, List]
x: List[Int] = List()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`breakOut` is defined like so:

```
def breakOut[From, T, To](implicit b: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, To]): CanBuildFrom[From, T, To]
```

So it cannot be used to *avoid* passing a `CanBuildFrom` into your `empty` method - it requires one itself. Luckily, it is easy to write - you want to create a `C[T]` out of `C[T]`, and the element type is `T`, so:

```
def empty(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[T], T, C[T]]): C[T] =
      Iterable.empty[T].map(x => x)(breakOut)
```

Tho since you have a `CanBuildFrom` instance anyway, the implementation using it directly is straightforward too:

```
def empty(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[T], T, C[T]]): C[T] =
      cbf().result()
```

Comment: One problem though, calling `empty` results in the following error: `Cannot construct a collection of type C[T] with elements of type T based on a collection of type C[T].`

Comment: Hmm, well it does work in the context i originally posted. I will investigate a bit more.

Comment: Ah, I was just forgetting to pass in the implicit in the right place (see answer update).